# Windows thread pools

Tags: c, mingw, threadpool

How is it possible to use Windows thread pools from plain `C`, or is `C++` required? Is it OK to use them with MinGW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Thread Pool API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a C API, it can be used either in C or C++.  Yes, it's ok to use them with MinGW—MinGW uses the same C runtime library that Microsoft's compilers use (unlike Cygwin, which uses the GNU C library).